# How to upload files to server using Putty (ssh)

Tags: ssh, putty

Can someone help me with commands? I'm trying to upload file to server based on linux.

Comment: Please clarify if the question is specifically about putty or if answers about any method for uploading via scp is fine.

Comment: @Alexander, it is specifically about PuTTY.

Comment: PuTTY seems to be both "the PuTTY project" (in lack of a better term) and the name of a specific executable/client named PuTTY, which is part of "the PuTTY project". Which do you mean? Are answers involving pscp on topic? And wich OS are you on? Are you trying to upload multiple files or a single file? What have you already tried?

Comment: @Alexander, the question is from person who is using PuTTY, trying to find a way to upload file. See his comment in accepted answer.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You need an scp client. Putty is not one. You can use WinSCP or PSCP. Both are free software.

Comment: I used WinSCP to upload file, but after it seemed worked i got that file on server =0 byte.

Comment: I cannot tell why. As RaShe suggest, it might be a network issue. Maybe you can look in to the log files on the server to get a hint. (sudo) ls -lr /var/log

Comment: Bitkinex (http://www.bitkinex.com/) is another viable option for this task

Comment: pscp is listed on the PuTTY download page, and really is an scp client: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 52):

`"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -scp file.py server.com:`

`file.py` will be uploaded into your `HOME` dir on remote server.

or when the remote server has a different user, use `"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -l username -scp file.py server.com:`

After connecting to the server pscp will ask for a password.

Comment: Get the message "More than one remote source not supported". What to do about this? running on Windows 8.1

Comment: @Erwinus, something is wrong with your command line arguments. See https://superuser.com/questions/511755/more-than-one-remote-source-not-supported-when-copying-files-via-pscp

Comment: This answers the initial question the best way, since PSCP is generally a part of Putty. So +1

Comment: Updated command: `"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -P 22 file.py username@ip_address_or_domain:` Also change port number (the number after `-P`) if the server listening different port for SSH. Another option, to upload another directory instead of home, use like this `"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -P 22 file.py username@ip_address_or_domain:/var/www/html`

Answer (score 17):

Use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) for file transfer over SSH, putty is only for SSH commands.

Comment: I used WinSCP to upload file, but after it seemed worked i got that file on server =0 byte.

Comment: Maybe it was a network error or something.

Comment: For me WinSCP did not worked though https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client worked great.