# Using Putty to import a sql file into the database

Tags: mysql, database, hosting, putty

I want to import an .sql file into a database on the server through command line.

I understand that I should use the follow line:

mysql -u username -p database_name < textfilewithsqlstatments.sql

the sql file is currently in my local folder, shall I upload it to the server first? how should I specify the directory for this file?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using Putty (ssh)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025404/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-putty-ssh)

Answer (score 16):

The line

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < textfilewithsqlstatments.sql
```

Assumes that the file is in the same directory that you are running the command from.

You should upload the file to the server and specify the path as

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < /path/to/file/on/server/textfilewithsqlstatments.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use the putty utility PLINK.EXE

Preferred configure the session with a key, to not need to put the password in all the connections, so simple use:

> plink  mysql -u username -p database_name <
>   textfilewithsqlstatments.sql

Considering that the file

> textfilewithsqlstatments.sql

is in your /home/user.

More information about PLINK: http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html

It works fine!

Answer (score 0):

STEP1:
enter your Hostname or I.P address and use port 22 @ putty.
If you are entering your hostname, leave out the http://www and simply enter yourdomain.com.

STEP2:
You can then enter your cPanel username and click enter

STEP3:
Then enter your cPanel password and click enter.

STEP4:
finally step is to enter the command line below

```
mysql -u database_user_name -p database_db_name < /home/alphabettechnologies/public_html/alphabet_webz.sql
```

and click enter. (make sure to replace the path with the correct address to your database. The filename for your SQL database file, You’ll also need to replace with your new database username and password.

```
mysql -u database_user_name -p database_db_name < /home/alphabet/public_html/db-backup.sql
```

STEP5: enter the db user password

Thats All, will be db imported